# GCC 11.2 from Ubuntu 21.10 and version in Compiler Explorer yield different output for a C-string used as a collection for iteration

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I'm getting two different results from GCC 11.2, one from Ubuntu 21.10 and the other from the version in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org).

The sample is an adaptation from Nicolai Josuttis' book, C++20 - The Complete Guide.

The issue is that with Ubuntu, when I pass a C string, both the lambda and the function emit a non-printable character for the null terminator, but that's not the case when I run the same program in Compiler Explore.

My assumption is that the version in Compiler Explorer is the correct one, but cannot determine why the issue is present in Ubuntu.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_collection_cpp20(const auto& collection) {
    for (const auto& element : collection) {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    auto print_collection = [](const auto& collection) {
        for (const auto& element : collection) {
            std::cout << element << '\n';
        }
    };

    print_collection("Hello"); // This is the deal breaker
    print_collection(std::string{"Hello"});

    print_collection_cpp20("HelloCpp20"); // and this one, too
    print_collection_cpp20(std::string{"HelloCpp20"});

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler version in Ubuntu 21.10 is as follows:

```
ubuntu1:$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The output of the program is just the letters followed by a new line.  In Ubuntu you'll see that there's an "extra" blank space--non-printable character that separates the output. If you use an IDE such as IntelliJIDEA, you'll see the rectangle that indicates a non-printable character.

If you have an idea of what's going on, please chime in.

Comment: Your envirnoment prints `'\0'` differently. Try casting `element` to `int` and see if the results differ. To be clear, the NULL-terminator is not printed when the loops traverse a `std::string`.

Comment: Correct, the std::string prints fine on both. It's the NULL terminator output that differs, but in Compiler Explorer it is not printed at all.

Comment: Well, it's a **non-printing** (or control) character, how it's managed depends on your terminal settings.